# How to sync Chrome bookmarks without logging in to Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I like Firefox Sync, but I prefer the Chrome browser. I don't use Chrome because it requires me to log in with my Google account to sync bookmarks. From a privacy point of view, I don't like that. Is there a way to use Chrome without logging in, but get my bookmarks synced across my machines?

I'm not necessarily interested in syncing between Chrome and firefox.

Comment: I just saw this https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035 Can I trust it? Why should I trust it?

Answer (score 1):

You can import/export your bookmarks for Chrome as a HTML file through the bookmark manager of Chrome.

If you export your bookmarks from your source Chrome, you will be able to import them in a new Chrome installation.

[More info](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en)